# Image array out of bounds in drop down menu

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I am working on a basic project with a JCombo box, when something is selected in the box the image changes. The window and image display, but when I select the second image from the JCombo box, I get an array out of bounds error. Please take a look:

```
public Dropdown(){
    super("The title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    box = new JComboBox (filename); //Automatically put the array in a list for us

    box.addItemListener(
            new ItemListener(){ //automatically implements itemlistener
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){ //invoked when dropdown menu button is selected
                    if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) //what icon did you select, prevents you from clicking on itself
                        picture.setIcon(firstpictureinarray[box.getSelectedIndex()]); //change it into that selected icon
                }

            }
    );

    add(box);
    picture = new JLabel (firstpictureinarray [0]);
    add(picture);

}
}
```

This is the line with the issue:

```
picture.setIcon(firstpictureinarray[box.getSelectedIndex()]); //change it into that selected icon
```

After reading a lot about similar errors I came to the conclusion to add both elements in the following array, but I got an error; so I commented that added part in:

```
private Icon[] firstpictureinarray = {new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename [0] /*, filename [1]*/))}; //code = pics
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Userinterfaces.Dropdown$1.itemStateChanged(main.java:34)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you so much for the time you are taking for reading this, I really appreciate the effort you are putting into helping a fellow programmer!

Comment: You have more ComboBox items than you have elements in your `firstpictureinarray `

Comment: How can I fix this then? I tried doing something like this: /*, filename [1]*/ next to my filename [2] but that brought up another error

Comment: Do you know how to do it?

Comment: What are the contents of `filename`?

Comment: private static String[] filename = {"swag.png", "code.png"};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firstpictureinarray` only contains a single item, but your combo box contains multiple items.

Try defining and initializing `firstpictureinarray` like this, so that the array and the combo box always contain the same number of items (which is the number of files):

```
private Icon[] firstpictureinarray = new Icon[filename.length];
for (int i = 0; i < filename.length; i++) {
    firstpictureinarray[i] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename [i]));
}
```

Also, you should consider renaming "firstpictureinarray" to something more accurate, like "picturearray".

Comment: Thanks cybersam, I will like and mark best answer as soon as I figure this out. I am not able to properly understand this line, I know what they do, but not how they do it. Can you give me a step by step list of what each command and .method() does? I will post it in the following comment. Again, I really appreciate your time!

Comment: if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) ;
       picture.setIcon(firstpictureinarray[box.getSelectedIndex()]);

Comment: I am slightly confused because aren't event.getStateChange() and ItemEvent.SELECTED the same thing?

Comment: The method `event.getStateChange()` gets the new state, and `ItemEvent.SELECTED` is a possible state. `(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED` is simply comparing the value returned by the method with the `SELECTED` state; and the result of that comparison could be true or false.

Comment: What do you mean it is a possible state?